# How to find 64-bit divisions in existing C code?

Tags: c, gcc, llvm-clang

Does anyone know a way of finding 64-bit divisions in an existing codebase? Possibly by introducing a compile error or warning for 64-bit division. (gcc or clang)?

Background is I would like to replace all 64-bit divisions in said code base with a custom function for example `a/b` would be replaced by `my64_div(a, b);`. To make it easier to port the code to ARM 32 bit platforms. 
I guess I could cross-compile it for ARM 32 and look at the compilation errors. Is there a way to do this without cross-compilation?

Possibly a python script with a cparser library that could find 64-bit divisions? I have used PyCLibrary for a different task before but I don't see a way to use it for this purpose. 
Any hints are appreciated.

**Edit:**
A little more background why I need this. There are 3 teams involved here.

1. Research team: they write their code without caring too much about 64-bit divisions.
2. My team: We integrate the research library in our code. And we make the final product. Which is delivered as source code.
3. Customer: Some of our customers will port this code to ARM 32-bit kernel. And they want to replace the 64-bit divisions with their own optimized functions.

Teams 1. and 2. use mostly 64 bit PCs to compile the code. It would be great to find 64-bit divisions at this stage, for one because they are expensive and we are trying to avoid them. So it would be great to have them flagged during nightly builds. 
Secondly, we want to make our customers' life easier. Meaning if we replace all 64-bit divisions by a custom function, they just need to replace function with another function. The rest of the source code can stay untouched.

The cross compilation and detecting __udivdi3 is certainly a possibility, and maybe the only option. But I was hoping there might be another solution out there.

Comment: No. You'll have to manually go through the codebase.

Comment: That's what I'm doing so far, but it is a lot of work :)

Comment: On systems that don't support 64-bit division; the compiler most likely injects a call to a library function (e.g. to `__udivdi3()`) that does 64-bit division so that software still works. Instead of replacing the 64 bit divisions in the original source, you could find/replace the library function with your own function.

Comment: @Brendan Or you could even implement it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to address the XY problem here: you don't need to. 64-bit division is part of the C language and is present in any valid C compiler. Normally on targets that don't have a native instruction for it (note: many don't even have one for 32-bit!) it's normally implemented as a library call to a library provided with the compiler.

If you really do want to find them, use the `nm` utility to look for references to these library functions from object files (e.g. `grep` its output), or `objdump -dr` to be able to see which function the reference is from. The typical naming convention initiated by GCC is `__udivdi3`, etc., but on ARM there might be a different name defined by the EABI that's used instead (something matching a pattern like `__aeabi_.*div.*`).